# Android and ksoup2

Tags: android, web-services, soap, soap-client, ksoap2

I'm trying to request some information from a server using ksoup2 for android. 
Here is the webservice SOAP info:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <HappySpeakGetEventsMethod xmlns="http://www.outsystems.com">
      <email>string</email>
      <password>string</password>
    </HappySpeakGetEventsMethod>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And here is my Android code:

```
 try {
                SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                Request.addProperty("email", "myemail@mail.com");
                Request.addProperty("password","mypassword");

                SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

                HttpTransportSE trnasport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                trnasport.debug = true;
                trnasport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

                Object resultsString =  soapEnvelope.getResponse();
                resultsString.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The main problem is that the request gets to the server and both fields are empty(like this "").
Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the anwser!
The namespace field was wrong and i had to add:

```
 soapEnvelope.dotnet=true;
```